# Why does yum not read updates to RPM repository file?

Tags: node.js, rpm, yum

On Amazon Linux, I was following [the guide](https://github.com/nodesource/distributions#no-root-privileges-3) of installing Node.js v16 via NodeSource RPM:

```
$ curl -fsSL https://rpm.nodesource.com/setup_16.x | sudo bash
```

The command above updates the repository file in `/etc/yum/yum.repos.d/nodesource-el7.repo`, such that when I run `yum list --showduplicates nodejs`, yum shows me all available version 16 of Node.js. No problem here.

But then, I decided to install v20 instead. So I run the command below, modifying yet again the `/etc/yum/yum.repos.d/nodesource-el7.rep`. This should let yum discover v20 distributions of Node.js:

```
curl -fsSL https://rpm.nodesource.com/setup_20.x | sudo bash -
```

The problem is, when I try to install Node.js v20 using `sudo yum install nodejs`, yum installs v16 instead. When I run `yum list --showduplicates nodejs`, yum still shows me the list of v16 Node.js, and not v20. It's as if yum doesn't know that the .repo was updated.

I try to use `yum clean all` in hopes for yum to discover the v20 Node.js repository, but it doesn't work. I used `yum clean metadata` and it worked for only a couple of times. As I kept experimenting by switching between v16 and v20 installations, in the end `yum list nodejs` rarely updates its list despite updates to the Node.js .repo.

Question: how do I tell yum to update its discoverable packages according to updates in `/etc/yum.repos.d/`? (The `nodesource-el7.repo` in my case.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After trying out different things, scouring the docs and going through a lot of trouble in the process, it seems that the command below is a fool-proof way to ensure that Yum reads its repositories correctly.

```bash
sudo rm -rf /var/cache/yum && yum clean all && yum makecache
```

- [`yum clean all`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/yum.8.html#:%7E:text=from%20the%20system.-,dnf%20clean%20all,-Does%20all%20of) cleans all sorts of temporary files.
- [`yum makecache`](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/6/html/deployment_guide/sec-working_with_yum_cache#idm140653418184304:%7E:text=to%20make%20sure%20that%20the%20cache%20is%20fully%20up%20to%20date%20with%20all%20metadata) recreates the Yum cache. It seems that `yum clean all` does not clear caches on the HTTP layer, and this command fixes that.
- `rm -rf /var/cache/yum` is to somehow fix the inconsistency brought by the previous 2 commands above. That is, the version displayed in `yum list <package>` can differ from the version installed via `yum install <package>`. Deleting the cache directory somehow fixes this.